# Raster Calculator Bug at start

Tags: raster, arcgis-desktop, gdal, arctoolbox, raster-calculator

I use ArcGIS 10.1 on a Windows XP. ArcGIS completely shuts down when I attempt to launch the "Raster Calculator" tool. Has this happened to someone else? Any ideas on how to solve this annoying issue? 
Otherwise, can I calculate the sum of raster values using command-line GDal?

Comment: Windows XP? Have you accepted some sort of OS update? I've experienced problems in the past when Internet Explorer updates.

Comment: Does raster calculator also fail when you try and run it through model builder? ArcMap may have trouble launching the dialog itself, not the tool. Please test this and let us know results so we can help you troubleshoot. See this link for more information: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/2005-Raster-calculator-in-ModelBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDAL will probably run better on Windows XP than ArcGIS 10.1.

Keep in mind that support from Microsoft for Windows XP is ending on April 8, 2014.  Not to say that arc won't work, but its harder to find people in the community to answer questions.

I would test this Raster Calculator issue myself but I upgraded my last xp box about a year ago (went with Linux Mint).

Best of luck.